# How to navigate to multiple ejs files in an html file without writing too many lines of code

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I  want to navigate to multiple ejs files in my html files without writing too many lines of code in my server.js
I have **Express** installed and my file extension hidden.
Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<a href = "/contact"> Contact Us </a>
<a href = "/about"> About </a>
<a href = "/pricing"> Pricing </a>
```

**server.js**

```
app.get("/contact", function (req, res){
   res.render("contact")
});

app.get("/about", function (req, res){
   res.render("about")
});

app.get("/pricing", function (req, res){
   res.render("pricing")
});
```

> Note that this method works perfectly

Now what if I have a lot of ejs files I want to link to my html.

Is there another way to write it so I don't have to write the same code over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an array of the commands you want to process and then loop it, like:

```
let commands = ['command1', 'command2', 'command3'];

for (let command of commands) {
    app.get(`/${command}`, function (req, res){
       res.render(command)
    });
}
```

This is admittedly a simplistic approach, you can elaborate this if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Example: Filename header.ejs: In this file, put your code for header or anything.

Now put this code in any place of content, index etc.

`<%- include('header'); %>`

('...' is for pathname)

You can use it anywhere and any number of times you desire like this:

```
<div> <%- include('header'); %> </div>
<div> <%- include('header'); %> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I think this old npm package does just what you wanted: [html-include](https://github.com/binocarlos/html-include)

Comment: Should explain your answer and not just add a link. Answers shouldn't rely on external sources to be answered.